# Converting .dxf to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, autocad

I have a .dxf file to convert to .shp.  Using ArcMap I've added the .dxf and tried exporting to .shp (various types, polyline, point, polygon) and also tried exporting to a gdb.  For the most part it works but some of the original polyline (or polygon) files come into ArcMap as points.  Has anyone come across this problem before and know of a solution?

Comment: Fme desktop trial ?

Comment: @Julien no fme.  I was using Autodesk plugin for google drive (free) and arcGIS info... or advanced I think it is now 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so using the Autodesk plugin on google drive I've found I can select the features in question, then explode them.  When I open them in arcGIS they are no longer points but instead the polyline features.

**update** I belive in CAD lingo, the features I was talking about are in fact blocks.  By exploding these you can win when importing to Arc